# Tensor Product with a Free Abelian Group

Tags: tensor-products, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

The following claim is made in Massey's *Singular Homology Theory*: If $G$ is any abelian group, and $F$ is a free abelian group with basis $\{T_\alpha\}$, then every element of $G \otimes F$ can be written uniquely as $a_1 \otimes T_1 + \cdots + a_l \otimes T_k$, for $T_1,\ldots,T_k$ basis elements and $a_1,\ldots,a_k \in G$.

I can see why every element of $G \otimes F$ can be written in this form, but I can't prove uniqueness. Even in the easiest case $F = \mathbb{Z}$ this is unclear: Why does $x \otimes 1 = 0$ imply $x = 0$? Handling this case will also cover the more general situation since tensor products distribute over direct sums.

Comment: This exact type of question still gives me nightmares from graduate school  :}  In the case $F=\Bbb Z$, am I right that $G\otimes \Bbb Z \cong G$ for any abelian group $G$? Is that enough?

Comment: Right that's exactly it - always forget that fact. Thanks!

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, to prove uniqueness it would suffice to find, for each such expression, an abelian group $A$ and a bilinear map $G\times F\to A$ under which the image of the element is nontrivial. For if there were two different expressions representing the same element, their different would represent the trivial element.